# itext 1.3.1 start wrapped table row directly on new page

Tags: java, itext

I have a problem I can not solve with itext 1.3.1, the content of a com.lowagie.text.Table cells is variable, often wraps to multiple lines. When the page changes the table is broken and the content continues on the new page. If the line were to end up on the new page can it to be written directly to the new page?

Comment: The class `com.lowagie.text.Table` has been removed from iText a very long time ago. iText 1.3.1 dates from May 2005. You should not expect an answer on your question. That version was EOL years ago! You should switch to using `PdfPTable`. (And you should upgrade!)

Comment: i know that this is a very old version, but i can't upgrade on this project.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that with Table class is impossibile, i used the method setCellsFitPage(true) but it didn't work.
I changed Table with PdfPTable and i applied setSplitLate(true), now it work